# Integral $\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}$

Tags: integration

$$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}$$

I tried to solve this integral, but I have no idea how to start this problem.

What should I do to solve this integral?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try writing it as $$\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1 - (x-1)^2}} \, dx$$ and using the substitution $x-1 = \sin \theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite as $$\int x\sqrt{\frac{x}{2-x}}dx$$ now substitute $$t=\sqrt{\frac{x}{2-x}}$$
This results in a rational integrand.